# How to create a sparks effect using CAReplicatorLayer with some randomness?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, particle-system, careplicatorlayer

Is it possible to create a convincing sparks effect using a CAReplicatorLayer particle system with some randomness?

If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

I think the new CAEmitterLayer will be a better fit.